# NameID , Assertion Attributes - Which one should I use and what they mean

Tags: wif, saml-2.0

I am doing an exercise of integrating my ASP.NET site with a IDP that sends SAML 2.0. Just now I have figured out all nitty gritty and got a 1000 feet view + how all things are wired up.

Now IDP team asks me what User Information I need , I obviously Know what I want but they had put a  choice of If I need to use NameID or assertion attributes.

I know from these links [link 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2010/02/17/name-identifiers-in-saml-assertions.aspx) , [SAML 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0) that NameID is a representation of current logged in user. So my question is just the NameID is not enough ? I need to request all additional information that I required about the user say Age, Address etc ? Or does NameID is capable of packaging all those information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of NameID as  the primary key.

Refer: [ADFS : Using the SAML NameID to map IdP / SP claims](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/03/adfs-using-saml-nameid-to-map-idp-sp.html).

However, all NameID does is pass some attribute (I normally use email) in the NameID format. You can only pass one attribute in this format.

If you need anything else like last name, age, roles etc. you need to pass these as assertions.